# Relationship serialiser Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

my serializers:

```
class ProductVariantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    value = serializers.CharField(source="option.name", read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ProductVariant
        fields = ['id', 'value', 'price',]
```

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    variants = ProductVariantSerializer(source="product", many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = "__all__"
```

my result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sS2Vw.png)

I need like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U90UM.png)